# How to compute checksum of entire file in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, checksum

How can we compute checksum for "entire" file data in Pentaho?

I know we can calculate checksum using "Add a checksum" function (But it returns checksum value "per row" for my CSV file input) and "Calculator" function (But it returns null or zero value as a checksum "per row" for my CSV file input)...

Instead **I want checksum for the entire file data and NOT per individual row**. How can we achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to compute checksum of the entire file.

I used "`User Defined Class`" step and `java.security.MessageDigest` class in Java to compute and return checksum of a file read using `FileInputStream`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java functions via the "Modified JavaScript Value" step like this ("filename" is a column with path to the file)

```
var md5_hash = '';
file = new Packages.java.io.File(filename);  
fileInputStream = new Packages.java.io.FileInputStream(file);
md5_hash = Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fileInputStream);
fileInputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, load the entire file in a single row using 'load file data in memory', apply a checksum to that, then do a cartesian or a stream lookup based on filename with your regular data flow.